# How to change an array inside state

Tags: reactjs

I want to update `results` by pushing new data in it !!!

data is an array in the state array,

```
 this.state = {

      comments: {
        results: []
      }
    }; 


 const new = {user : "users"};
 var comments= this.state.comments.results[0].data;
 var  comment= data.push(new);
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are overcomplicated. Just do this:

```
this.state = {
  comments: {
    results: []
  }
}; 
const new = {user : "users"};
var comments = this.state.comments.results[0].data;
this.setState({
  comments: {
    ...this.state.comments,
    results: [
      ...this.state.comments.results,
      new
    ]
  }
});
```

The `...` (spread operator) basically just takes all the properties/elements of an object/array and dumps them into the containing object/array. For objects, any additional properties defined after the spread operation will overwrite the properties added by the spread if their keys are the same.

Comment: TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance] >>.error

Comment: @amanirose Then either `comments` or `results` is not an object/array. If your actual code looks exactly like this then it should work. So there's something you're not showing us.

Comment: variable comments did't define it still not lit

Comment: ```     const dataa = data.Comment;
  
  

       var comments = this.state.comments.results[0].comments;
     this.setState({
  comments: {
    ...this.state.comments,
    results: [
      ...this.state.comments,
      dataa
    ]
  }```

Comment: @amanirose You have a typo. The second `...this.state.comments` should be `...this.state.comments.results`.

Comment: Thank you very much ...i searched about spread operator  and learned it, and ya i solved that what i did>>>>>  @chrispytoes

Comment: ```                                                                                                                                                         const newdata = data.Comment
      var comments = this.state.comments.results[0].comments;
      const cc  = comments.push(newdata)
      this.setState({
        comments: {
          ...this.state.comments,
          comments: cc
        }
      });
    }                                                                                                                                           ```

Answer (score 0):

Use ReactJS state and array `push()` method:

```
this.state = { result: [] };
var newStateArray = oldArray.push("new element");
this.setState({ result: newStateArray });
```

Comment: There are many item in results i dont want to update it ,,i want just to update the data array